# Exporting an Excel file from R with columns color coded?

Tags: r

When exporting the excel file the columns are not color coded. I am using the condformat package. i know that condformat creates a html file, i am using the condformat2excel command but its not color coding the columns i need. any help or tip are welcome thank you.

```
library(readxl)
library(condformat)
teast1 <- read_excel("Kenilworth_DataIssues-testR.xls",sheet = "Data Cleanup")
color_pick <- function(column) {
  sapply(column,
         FUN = function(value) {
           if (value >= 25) {
             return("red")
           } else {
             return("dodgerblue")
           } 


        })
}

color_pick2 <- function(column2) {
  sapply(column2,
         FUN = function(value2) {
           if (value2 >9000) {
             return("red")
           } else if(value2 < 8000) {
             return("dodgerblue")
           }else{
             return("green")

           } 


         })

}
condformat2excel(teast1,"flip.xlsx",sheet_name = "lebeon",overwrite_wb = FALSE,overwrite_sheet = TRUE)%>%
rule_fill_discrete("PlannedPremiseTime",expression = color_pick(PlannedPremiseTime),colours = identity)%>%
rule_fill_discrete("PostalCode",expression = color_pick2(PostalCode),colours = identity)
```